# python use test if value of a pandas dataframe is in membership of a set denoted by another column

Tags: python, pandas, set

if I have the following csv file test.csv:

```
C01,45,A,R
C02,123,H,I
```

where I have define sets `R` and `I`  as

```
R=set(['R','E','D','N','P','H','K'])
I=set(['I','H','G','F','A','C','L','M','P','Q','S','T','V','W','Y'])
```

I want to be able to test if the string `A` is a member of set `R` (which is false) and if string `H` is a member of set `I` (which is true). I have tried to do this with the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd

I=set(['I','H','G','F','A','C','L','M','P','Q','S','T','V','W','Y'])
R=set(['R','E','D','N','P','H','K'])

with open(test.csv) as f:
    table = pd.read_table(f, sep=',', header=None, lineterminator='\n')
table[table.columns[3]].astype(str).isin(table[table.columns[4]].astype(str))
```

i.e. I am trying to do the equivalent of `A in R` or rather `table.columns[3] in table.columns[4]` and return TRUE or FALSE for each row of data.

The only problem is that using the final line the two rows return TRUE. If I change the final line to

```
table[table.columns[3]].astype(str).isin(R)
```

Then I get

```
0   FALSE
1   TRUE
```

which is correct. It seems that I am not referencing the set name correctly when doing `.isin(table[table.columns[3]].astype(str))`

any ideas?

Comment: I am confused as to what you are trying to check. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Do you want to use the letter `R` from the file as the set name? If so, your best bet is using a dictionary.

Comment: Basically A is not in the set R, but H is in the set I. I want to print the membership outcome of comparing columns 3 and 4

Comment: "composing columns 3 and 4"...? Your set R has no relation to the value "R" (a string) in your `DataFrame`.

Comment: row by row  I want to do:

'A' in R
'H' in I

where R and I are sets

Comment: You should really try to grok my previous comment: Your set `R` has no relationship with the value `"R"` (a string) in your `DataFrame`. In my answer, I had to *impose* that relationship.

Comment: I do not wish to test if the string "R" is in set `R`. I want to test (in the first row) if the string "A" is a member of set `R` - which is false.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the following:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
     0    1  2  3
0  C01   45  A  R
1  C02  123  H  I

In [22]: R=set(['R','E','D','N','P','H','K'])
    ...: I=set(['I','H','G','F','A','C','L','M','P','Q','S','T','V','W','Y'])
    ...:
```

You could do something like this:

```
In [23]: sets = {"R":R,"I":I}

In [24]: df.apply(lambda S: S[2] in sets[S[3]],axis=1)
Out[24]: 
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool
```

Fair warning, `.apply` is slow and doesn't scale with larger data very well. It is there for convenience and a last resort.

Comment: thanks - how would this be implemented using dictionaries (if i should not be using dataframes?)

Comment: @brucezepplin I couldn't opine without understanding what it is you are trying to accomplish.